# Past simple sentence

Tags: past-tense

I've just read the next sentences:

> 'I wanted to see her again', John said.
>
> 'And you did, you **did see** her again', Jennifer said.

Why not say "you **saw** her again"?

Comment: At times, we use these verbs to emphasize or highlight. It's just that case!

Comment: Aside from emphasis, people have different writing styles, i.e., choice of words, structure, etc. (Writing style - the manner in which an author chooses to write to his or her readers.)

Answer (score 0):

In this case the change is from an imperfect tense to a perfect tense - which emphasises that the seeing happened and was over.   In context, it implies a greater degree of finality than (the grammatically correct) alternative, "you saw her again".

Comment: Sorry, what is an imperfect tense in English?

Comment: It is just an ***emphatic do*** usage.

Comment: There are several, the simplest is the past imperfect. more commonly known now as the past continuous now, apparently.  (That change has snuck up me).

Comment: Yes, indeed. The past continuous looks like the imperfect in my language and in the other Latin (Romance) languages.